# Optimizing CLPFD performance (cumulative, global_cardinality)

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I've written some predicates to solve large scheduling problem and they work well but I'd like them to have some better performance. I've run `profile/1` and what I see is that CLPFD-related predicates take 99% of the time. Especially `garbage_collect` - it takes 37% of the execution time.

Now, what can I do? My code isn't especially complex, it uses a lot of `cumulative/2` and some `global_cardinality/2`, nothing special above that. I've tried some different options for `labeling/1` (ff, ffc, bisect), but there is no difference (bisect makes things worse, actually). I've tried raising memory limits with `set_prolog_stack/2` (global limit, local limit, global min_free, local min_free).

Is there anything more I can do?

Are there any alternative imlpementations of `cumulative/2` or `global_cardinality/2` which could have better performance?

Comment: Consider to use [`library(clpz)`](https://github.com/triska/clpz) which is the successor to `library(clpfd)`. It runs on SICStus. On SWI, there are many problems with the constraint-mechanism - in particular in the context of global constraints.

Comment: @false, I would consider it, but I don't have so much money to buy commercial licence. :-(

Comment: Start with the evaluation license which is for free!

Comment: Post some of your code, so people who have (already) have access to SICStus and SWI (and possibly other systems) can work with it!

Comment: FYI, SICStus has a specialized `multi_cumulative/3` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code and just the problem domain, all I can suggest is
consider adding redundant constraints to further cut down search space.

- User considerations concerning properties of valid solutions can suggest redundant constraints
- More generic approaches ex. dual [Thesis](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01745888/document)  [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166218X1730238X)
- Another approach is to identify symmetry in solutions that are not desired then add constraints that remove such symmetry. I.e.

  - one can be "easily" deduced from another
  - they are "similar" in some way e.g. cost